# Unexpected behavior of Jetpack Compose Modifier.animateContentSize() animation and State

Tags: android, animation, android-jetpack-compose, android-animation, android-jetpack

I just started experimenting with Jetpack Compose animations. The code I'm working with is part of [this](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-compose-woof-animation) Jetpack Compose codelab. The complete code is available on [this Github page](https://github.com/google-developer-training/basic-android-kotlin-compose-training-woof/blob/material/app/src/main/java/com/example/woof/MainActivity.kt).

---

This is the UI of the app:

[image: main screen] When the expand more arrow is clicked, the card shows 2 Text composables wrapped in a Column. like so:
[image: Expand more arrow clicked]
I want to animate the list item card such that when I click the expand more arrow it would have high spring bounce animation, BUT when I click the arrow again to collapse, I want to have low bounce animation. like so:

[image: Wanted animation: Bouncy on expand only]

However, I'm getting an animation that looks bouncy on expand more AND collapse. like so:

[image: Unwanted animation: Bouncy on expand more and expand less]

```
@Composable
fun DogItem(
    dog: Dog,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
    var expanded by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    val bounciness = if (expanded) Spring.DampingRatioLowBouncy else Spring.DampingRatioHighBouncy
    Card(modifier = modifier) {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .animateContentSize(
                    animationSpec = spring(
                        dampingRatio = bounciness,
                        stiffness = Spring.StiffnessMedium
                    )
                )
                .background(color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primaryContainer)
        ) {
            Row(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .padding(dimensionResource(R.dimen.padding_small))
            ) {
                DogIcon(dog.imageResourceId)
                DogInformation(dog.name, dog.age)
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))
                ExpandButton(
                    expanded = expanded,
                    onClick = {
                        expanded = !expanded
                    },
                )
            }
            if (expanded) {
                DogHobby(
                    dog.hobbies,
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(
                        start = dimensionResource(R.dimen.padding_medium),
                        top = dimensionResource(R.dimen.padding_small),
                        end = dimensionResource(R.dimen.padding_medium),
                        bottom = dimensionResource(R.dimen.padding_medium)
                    )
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here the `DogItem` composable represents a single list item of `LazyColumn`. I added `expanded` to keep track of the list item state. In the initial composition, I set it to `false`. based on that the `bounciness` variable is set to `Spring.DampingRatioHighBouncy` I used that variable in the column's `Modifier.animateContentSize()` to specify the bounciness of the animation. when the `ExpandButton` is clicked it reverses the boolean state of `expanded` when that happens a recomposition should happen, but this time `expanded` is `true` because of that the `bounciness` variables should be set to `Spring.DampingRatioLowBouncy`. I thought this solution would give this result:

[image: expected the wanted animation]

however, I got this:

[image: unwanted animation]

What is going on?